# How to resolve error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl?

Tags: java, heroku, server, jersey, glassfish

I am getting this error when I am trying to add data to Heroku PostgreSQL database through GlassFish server.

The database adding is working properly when I am adding it directly by the client.

The error is:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;Ljava/util/Collection;Lsun/security/ssl/SessionId;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHello(ClientHandshaker.java:709)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:984)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:919)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
>           at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:40)
>           at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:435)
>           at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:94)
>           at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
>           at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
>           at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:195)
>           at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
>           at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
>           at packageData.Data.getConnection(Data.java:17)
>           at packageData.Data.postData(Data.java:122)
>           at packageServer.Server.getData(Server.java:51)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       ]]

I am not able to understand why this error is coming up when I am going through the server and not when I am going through the client.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the question with the answer does not solve the problem now.

Comment: Yes, but it is the same problem. It is better to concert the efforts to solve the problem in one spot.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe but that question is no longer active, the question was last active 11 months ago. There will be no new answers on that question, and the problem still persists.

Comment: This question need not be deleted. Everybody who sees this new question and knows the answer will find the other question and can answer it. I don't think this reduces your chances to get a good answer, it makes it easier for others to find it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I doubt that, people don't usually visit the duplicated question if they see one being marked as duplicate because duplicated questions are mostly solved problems.

Comment: Ok, I have voted for re-opening, since you believe it will attract more interest then. I'd put a bounty on the original question instead ...

Comment: Anyway, it seems to some kind of version incompatibility between Java components. Experiment with different versions of everything...